# Question about differentiability at an interval.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

> Let $f:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable function for which
> $f'\left(x\right)\cdot f'\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)<0$ for every
> $0<x\ne1$. Then $f'(1)=0$

I have this question, and I was wondering how to switch the fact the f is differentiable for every positive x into differentiable in a chosen interval that will help me with my proof..
I tried to make quiet a general interval in $[\frac{1}{x},x]$ but I'm afraid that I can't acctualy do that, and that it's not accurate..

**d.** True

We know $f$ is differential in $(0,\infty)$, therefore $f$ is also differentiable in the interval $[\frac{1}{x},x]$ for any $x ∈ R$ such that $0<\frac{1}{x}<1<x$.

Since $f'\left(x\right)\cdot f'\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)<0$, by Darboux's theorem there exist a point $c ∈ R$ such that

$\frac{1}{x} < c < x$ and $f'(c)=0$.

Assume toward contradiction that c ≠ 1, then  we have $f'\left(c\right)\cdot f'\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)<0$.

But since $f'(c)=0$, we have $0 \cdot f'\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)<0 \ \ \ ➜ \ \ \ 0 < 0$. Contradiction!

Therefore $c = 1$ and $f'(1) = 0$.

Comment: Your proof looks alright. For your question about differentiability I recommend to look at the definition of it again. Differentiability is a local property, so that differentiability only depends on small intervals. I also recommend you to look again at what you have written, and make it a bit more precise and clear, because you lack a bit the good style.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Darboux Theorem Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3979965/darboux-theorem-question)

Answer (score 0):

As @Proxava said, your proof is OK.

You can also show that $f$ is strictly monotone on $(0,1] \ \& \ [1,+\infty)$, in opposite directions.